# Is it possible to derive a formula for calculating stair thickness in vertical direction?

Tags: geometry

Stairs has constant step height (a) and various step length (b1, b2, ..bn). Thickens is constant everywhere (t). Need to find a formula to calculate distance L1, L2,..Ln if the S1, S2,..Sn are know.

[image: 1]

Comment: Are the $L_n$ meant to be centred in the middle of the steps?

Comment: No, Ln could be at any distance from the start of the stair (Sn). Even though I'm struggling to find solutions also for the special case where it is at the middle..

Comment: If the step has similar length, then this formula seems to work: L_n=a(bn - Sn + b1 + b2 + ⋯ b(n-1) ) / bn + (t√(a^2 + bn^2 )) / bn. But if the length changes drastically it fails..

Comment: You have featured the white line as a pure translation of the bottom line ; according to your constraint  (constant thickness t), it shouldn't be so. In my understanding, the white line is what is called an offset curve or dilated curve of the bottom line.

Comment: You are right - white is an offset curve for the bottom curve (or vice versa). About the thickness you are also right - it's "almost" the same everywhere. To truly be the same those corners for the bottom curve should be rounded.

Comment: You say the S1,S2,... are known. Are they arbitrary ? I am puzzled by the fact that $S_2$ corresponds exactly to a step change on your example (pure chance ?)

Comment: It is clear that you can not - given the values you have it seems you could move the thickness line for the given values. At least one point is required for the thickness. Do you assume the black and white lines to be "parallel"?

Comment: Jean - Yes, that's right, Sn could be any distance from the stair start till the end. So one case would be when S corresponds to step change (as S2 in this example). After spending some more time on this I start to realize that there is no easy solution here. Seems that theory of offset curves should be involved, what means that solution includes calculus. https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2014/124240/

Comment: Moti - well black line is an offset from the white line. So the thickness is kind of the same every where. Unfortunately with offset lines there is cases where the offsets intersects or creates gaps. I started to realize that the given problem is much more complex than I was thinking. (see my previous comment)